# How to select scenario when using AutoConfigureWireMock in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, wiremock

Using the following example of AutoConfigureWireMock, how can I select the scenario I want to use in my test?

Assuming that scenario1 is used in another test and cannot be changed

```
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs = "classpath:/stubs")
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleTest {
     @Test
     public void test(){
          //set scenario scenario2
          //assert get is 404
     }

}

{
  "request": {
    "scenarioName": "scenario1",
    "urlPattern": "/items",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200
  }
}


{
  "request": {
    "scenarioName": "scenario2",
    "urlPattern": "/items",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a WireMock server starts, [all Scenarios are in a state of "Started"](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/#scenarios) You'll need to specify that as the starting state for the scenario you want first.

```
{
  "request": {
    "scenarioName": "My Scenario",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
    "newScenarioState": "State 2",
    "urlPattern": "/items",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200
  }
}


{
  "request": {
    "scenarioName": "My Scenario",
    "requiredScenarioState": "State 2",
    "newScenarioState": "Started",
    "urlPattern": "/items",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

In the above, the first response will be returned, changing the scenario state. The next time you hit that endpoint, the second response will be returned, changing the scenario state again. (Changing the scenario state is optional -- you can leave a scenario in "Started" or a custom scenario state after a mapping is served up.)

If your requests were slightly different, you could instead differentiate them through the use of priority:

```
{
    "priority": 1,
    "request": {
        "urlPattern": "/items",
        "method": "GET",
        "queryParameters": {
            "myParam": {
                "equals": "200"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
         "status": 200
    }
}

{
    "priority": 2,
    "request": {
        "urlPattern": "/items",
        "method": "GET",
    },
    "response": {
         "status": 404
    }
}
```

Finally, if none of those solutions work for you, you can [use the admin endpoints](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/) to modify the mappings once you have started WireMock.